# How to set protected "write" rules for firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to set rules for my firebase database that only the current signed in user can delete and update their own data. I have the following rules I want to write protect it. These are my rules that I need to correct.

```
{
"rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth !=null"
}
}
```

This is my data

[image]

```
StorageReference ref=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("ExtendedPosts").push();
```

Comment: There is no `push()` method in a `StorageReference`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference

Comment: Also note that your rules didn't come through. Please edit your question to include them as text (no screenshots). While you're at it, it's also better to have the JSON as text instead of a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for editing my post. Can you please set rules for me I have a  project to submit and the deadline is near. I am a noob I will appreciate your help.

Comment: only the current signed in user can delete and update it, so can others read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Anyone can read only sign in users can write      
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

If your case is "The User can only update/delete their own data", you need to restructure your database design.

you need to save those things under userId node.

Comment: I want all the users to read the data. but only the current signed in user can write their data.

Comment: can only the User write their own data, or any signed-in user can write any data?

Comment: Then you need to save the post data under its user-id node. otherwise, you can not achieve ur goal

Comment: I already made my app I don't want to mess it up with reconstructing.